# Retrieve Mobile all Phone numbers or contacts using Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Am building a small phonegap app that will require the registered users to export or retrieve all the phone numbers in their contact list and imsert it into mysql database via php.

All trying to do is to get the all the contact list(phone numbers) via phonegap api and pass the result in div so that i can further pass the div as form variables and then insert the contacts to datbase.

I have tried the phonegap API documentation but could not get it to work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You will need to explain why you could not "get it to work". Did you use a procedure such as in http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Getting-Contact-List-With-Contact-Information-From-Android-Devices-using-PhoneGap-2275.php? And how did it fail?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the find method of the contacts API and do not filter, it should return them all:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init() {

    navigator.contacts.find(
        [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName],
        gotContacts,
        errorHandler);

}

function errorHandler(e) {
    console.log("errorHandler: "+e);
}

function gotContacts(c) {
    console.log("gotContacts, number of results "+c.length);
    for(var i=0, len=c.length; i<len; i++) {
        console.dir(c[i]);
    }
}
```